# Godaddy domain registrar, Nginx listening on 443 and not accepting connections from hostname, direct connect to IP works

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, https, dns

## The Problem

Whenever I connect to my website via the direct ip, example: "https://my-ip" the website loads fine. My DNS is pointed towards "https://my-ip" as well. I am running nginx serving a react frontend and reverse proxying HTTPS calls into HTTP calls to my Django backend. However attempting to connect to my website via the hostname, example [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com) fails with a 404, which you can see by attempting to connect to [www.holdengjuka.com](http://www.holdengjuka.com). My domain registrar is godaddy. I am using a self-signed security certificate (LetsEncrypt).

Comment: You're using GoDaddy's domain forwarding with masking, the website is loaded in a frame and browsers will refuse to load it due to invalid cert. Easiest to not using the domain forwarding at all, create a proper A/AAAA DNS record then setup the cert with LetsEncrypt

Comment: Thanks, I've spent a while trying to properly format this question should I delete it or leave it up as is and remove the improperly formatted stuff?

Comment: If you can fix it through the steps I described might as well just edit the question then create a self-answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer to help others, I also did the same mistake the first time I try implementing HTTPS pre-LetsEncrypt era (I end up using Cloudflare, which is still a great option today)

Comment: Update: It worked for about 15 minutes but now the LetsEncrypt certificate is throwing an NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID error. The website is at www.holdengjuka.com. I'm stumped, I was editing the nginx config to work on the backend reverse proxy and entered the proxy_bind command, got an error where the site wouldn't load after, and then deleted the line because it was breaking things. I can't imagine that would invalidate the certificate and break the site though? I would assume what I was doing was unrelated.

Comment: Ah, when you created the cert, you should enter all the domain and subdomains you use, eg in your case it should be www.holdengjuka.com and holdengjuka.com, right now the cert is only valid for holdengjuka.com. Also, one of your A records point to AWS, but it only return a 301 to your IP address, I'm assuming you're setting up a CDN, in that case re-check their documentation

Comment: I used this command, which should have set it up for both holdengjuka.com and www.holdengjuka.com, right?
Also this was the output I got:
Renewing an existing certificate for holdengjuka.com and www.holdengjuka.com
(I made it a second time after it started throwing the aforementioned error). I'm confused how the certificate is only configured for holdengjuka.com? I think the AWS A record is a default one GoDaddy had, I'll try deleting it. My setup is a React frontend running on NGINX that pulls content w/HTTP from a Django backend running on LAN, which NGINX forwards back to the client.

Comment: I deleted the GoDaddy domain forwarding and looked again for the AWS A record, which I remember there being at least one of but I don't see it anymore. Also the command I used ( I forgot to paste it: sudo certbot --nginx -d holdengjuka.com -d www.holdengjuka.com), Should I show here all of the A records that I have?

Comment: First column is the type, second column is the name, and last is the Data:  A   @   15.197.142.173   |||

A   @   3.33.152.147   |||

A   @   73.169.221.60   |||


A   *holdengjuka.com   73.169.221.60 ||||


CNAME   www   holdengjuka.com

Comment: Is 34.102.136.180 your server?

Comment: My server is 73.169.221.60.

Comment: Then remove it from your records https://dnschecker.org/#A/www%20holdengjuka.com

Comment: Once I removed GoDaddy's domain forwarding my hostname resolves to the GoDaddy website (34.102.136.180). You mentioned I didn't need the domain forwarding, so I'm assuming there must be some sort of misconfiguration of the DNS records and it's reverting to default behavior. I'm performing the DNS record management from the GoDaddy website, should I use some other resource to configure the DNS A records?

Comment: Odd, GoDaddy docs mention removing forwarding should unlock the A record entries, you probably need to check with the CS about it

Comment: i would change the title of this question as it has not much to do with nginx itself. It's alot broader than nginx and mainly deals with general knowledge of what you want to accomplish - there is no harm in that and i encourage you to up your curiosity game and learn/understand what you tackle and what it involves. Have fun!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Martheen's advice, I created an A certificate on GoDaddy.com pointing to my IP, using these instructions: https://www.godaddy.com/help/add-an-a-record-19238. I used a wildcard for the domain name, e.g:   *.mywebsite.com

I then used the following tutorial to create a LetsEncrypt certificate: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-22-04 and ran into a problem where it failed to create a certificate:

"Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: nginx)."

Since I had manually configured the NGINX configuration to enable SSL already for the site, it couldn't make a certificate.
So that problem was that I needed to make the website accessible by HTTP, and the method in the tutorial then automatically configures it to become an HTTPS site. Now the site is served fine over HTTPS! Thanks again Martheen, wish I could upvote you but my account is too new it seems.

UPDATE: I had further problems with GoDaddy and A records, I had to delete my A record that looked like this: [A @ Parked] and add these records: [A @ my-ip] and [A *holdengjuka.com my-ip] where my-ip is my actual IP.

Additionally, you must delete ALL Domain Forwarding in the Domain Forwarding section. You should be able to get to your website using your domain name with only the addition of A records and the removal of that "Parked" A record. Also it may not appear to update on your end if your DNS or browser still has your website cached, so go to your website using the full URL, e.g https://www.holdengjuka.com, to figure out if your website is being served properly. Alternatively you can also use the curl command on linux. Example curl [www.holdengjuka.com](http://www.holdengjuka.com)